# Explanation of 'little o' notation in the context of Fréchet derivatives

Tags: calculus, frechet-derivative

Consider the function $x^{2}$. Its Fréchet derivative should be $2x$ which is confirmed by evaluating the definition of Fréchet derivative
$$
\lim_{|h|\rightarrow0}{\frac{(x + h)^2 - x^{2}- 2xh}{|h|}=\lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^{2} + 2xh +h^{2} - x^{2} - 2xh}{|h|}} = \lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^{2}}{|h|} = \lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0}\frac{|h|^{2}}{|h|} = \lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0}|h|=0
$$
From the other hand, first order expansion ($f(x + h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + o(|h|)$) must also be true. And for the function in question it is
$$
(x + h)^{2} = x^{2} + 2xh + h^{2}.
$$
And I have doubts about $h^{2} \in o(|h|)$ because $f(x) \in o(g(x))$ is defined as $\lim_{x \rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$. Applying this definition to $h^{2}$ gives
$$
\lim_{|h|\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{h^{2}}{|h|} = \lim_{|h|\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{|h|^{2}}{|h|} = \lim_{|h|\rightarrow+\infty} |h| \neq 0.
$$
This should mean that $h^{2} \not\in o(|h|)$ but because this function is Fréchet differentiable first order expansion must hold. What am I missing?

My explanation is that in the context of Fréchet derivatives $f(x) \in o(g(x))$ means $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ but this is not the usual definition of 'little o' notation, so I am not sure if this explanation is reasonable.

Comment: derivatives are all about local properties, not values as $x\to\infty$. $o()$ and $O()$  can be defined with $h\to 0$ also and this is the version that should be used. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation): "Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends **towards a particular value** or infinity". For this reason, every time you see $O(.)$ you should strictly speaking, always have "as $x\to x_0$" paired with it e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinitesimal_asymptotics

Comment: Your explanation is correct. If by typical notation you mean in the analysis of asymptotics of algorithms in computer science, then yes. But in math, we use $g= o(f)$ as $x\to a$ to mean g is really really small compared f when we let x get close to a. And sometimes it it only implicit what a is, but you should not just assume a is always infinity.

Comment: Thank you for your answers